# not able to convert from BSON type string to Date on aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using the below code to get the month from the Date field in the MongoDB collection
I want to use extractMonth() in aggregation-Spring Data MongoDb

```
ProjectionOperation project = project("Id").andExpression("Date").extractMonth().as("month");
GroupOperation group = group("Id", "month").count().as("count");
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(project, match, group).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build());
DBObject resultset = mMongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, collectionName, JSONObject.class).getRawResults();
```

But I am getting below error:

> Can't convert from BSON type string to Date on aggregation pipeline

Sample data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "001",
    "createDate" : "2020-04-29T09:53:40.356+0000",
    "createdBy" : "abc",
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "002",
    "createDate" : "2020-03-16T22:59:42.023+0000",
    "createdBy" : "cde",
}
```

type of the `Date` field in the collection: `String`

`Spring-data-MongoDB version: 1.6.0 release`

How do I proceed to get results with the above version?

Comment: You should **never** store Data/Time values as string, use proper `Date` objects. As you don't provide any sample data we cannot tell you how to convert it.

Comment: Sample data updated @WernfriedDomscheit